# Как в вордпресс БД заменять данные в строке

Tags: mysql, wordpress, база-данных

Как  в WP в таблице БД заменить нужные значения в строке.
Использую

```
$result = $wpdb->replace( $table, $arr);
```

где

```
        $arr = array( 
            'id'            => setValue($data->data[$i]->id), 
            'home'          => setValue($data->data[$i]->number), 
            'book_status'   => setValue($status_ru[$data->data[$i]->status]),
            'rooms'         => setValue($data->data[$i]->rooms_amount),
            'phase'         => setValue($phase_ru[$data->data[$i]->sectionName]),
            'full_area'     => setValue($data->data[$i]->area->area_total),
            'life_area'     => setValue($data->data[$i]->area->area_living),
            'kitchen_area'  => setValue($data->data[$i]->area->area_kitchen),
            'price'         => setValue($data->data[$i]->price->value),                        
        );
```

В самой же строке таблицы БД всего 25 параметров из 9 приведенных.
Применяю replace() и данная функция заменяет только 9 приведенных, остальные 16 параметров очищает.

Знаю, что есть еще функция update().

Но мне необходимо получить данные и если данные с таким ID есть в таблице, то обновить данные в строке в этим ID. Если такого ID нет в таблице, то добавить новую строку с этим ID. Поэтому принципу функция replace() казалось бы почти подходила.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу так:

```
$row = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT id FROM $table WHERE id = ".$id );

if ( $row > 0 ) {
   // Есть данные
   $result = $wpdb->update( $table, $arr, array( 'id' => $id ) );
} else {
   // нет данных
   $result = $wpdb->insert( $table, $arr);
}
```

Comment: Я вам ровно то же самое в своем ответе написал

Answer (score 1):

`$wpdb->replace()` всегда заменяет все поля таблицы. Если вы не указываете какие-то поля, то они будут очищены, что у вас и происходит.

Чтобы делать замену 9 из 25 полей, вам надо сначала выполнить `get_row()` с нужным id, заменить в полученном массиве 9 полей из 25, и записать полный массив из 25 элементов назад с помощью `$wpdb->replace()`. По-другому MySQL не работает.

Answer (score 0):

> Как в WP в таблице БД заменить нужные значения

Если интересует как это сделать *правильно*, то
Вар1. С пом плагинов, работающий с сериализованными данными. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Вар2. Скрипта https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Вар3. [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/)

Если же речь о написании кода в своём плагине или теме, но нужно использовать функции ВП вида`*update*`.

Comment: Речь идет о написании собственного плагина. Синхронизация данных БД с данными полученными по API

Comment: @Александр Используй функции ВП. Класс wpdb нужен только в очень исключительных случаях.